Is the UPU POST*CODE database compatible with UN/LOCODE codes?
Dataset

I refer to https://www.upu.int/en/postal-solutions/programmes-services/addressing-solutions (as https://gis.stackexchange.com/revisions/182302/1 cites).
Rationale

Per this letter by the Department of State of the USA to the UPU, it appears that UN/LOCODE values are certainly utilized to an extent. Consequently, I would presume that they are compatible.
Question

I ask because I frequently use UN/LOCODE location codes when directing mail, and they're always sent to the correct location. However, I want to ensure that this isn't due to mere luck.
